# Javascript Print command for Open Drawer

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I'm using a localhost (windows 7) Point of Sale using PHP and MySQL, and all i need to do now is to open drawer once i click "Cash Button".
I own V-tech Cash Drawer USB interface (Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM3)) - As shown in device manager.
According to its manual, the only way to open this drawer is to create a printer and set it as a default and choosing COM3. I have created one, and I tested it using this code via Google Chrome as my browser to access POS

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print Test</button>
```

It opens a Print view page, then i click on Print...and it Opens the Cash Drawer !! But Clicking on the same "Print Test" button, it will be queued because the first print was not cleared from  print job status.

I've found a possible solution, but I have not tried to test it [How To cancel Printing or to Delete Print Job](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946737) - **Method D**

Also How would i Disable Google chrome print view, Or if there is a possible way to directly print once clicking on "Cash Button". I've noticed about PHP printer_open as follows :

```
 <?php
$handle = printer_open("Xerox Phaser 6120 PS");
$handle = printer_open();
?>
```

And I get this error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\frame\print.php on line 2**

Is there a possible way for doing it ? Thank You

Comment: seems like u dont include printer library. check this: http://www.php.net/manual/printer.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

You can you use --disable-print-preview in the command line when starting chrome.
http://techlogon.com/2012/03/29/how-to-disable-print-preview-in-chrome/
does not seem to work however with raw printing ie with zpl commands to a zebra printer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in FireFox easily.  Go to about:config, filter with "printer".

Find "print.always_print_silent" and set to true.

Anything now printed from FireFox goes directly the default printer skipping the Printer Selection Dialog.

Remember that PHP only happens on the SERVER, so it is even more removed from the hardware the browser is running on than Javascript.